# sentry onpremise how to set domain name?

Tags: sentry

We have been using old sentry (like 6.*)

We are trying to use the latest onpremise sentry with docker

We don't care about old data, starting fresh is fine.

When I go to the setting page for client-dsn, it has our server's domain name set.
Where did the docker pick this up? and how can I change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I have seen th FQDN is taken automatically by Sentry. When doing the first login you are able to set the Root name and there you can change it.

**Edit-21.07.2020:** As I currently need to do some digging i came across the function:

```
sentry config set system.url-prefix
```

or you can set it inside these files:

```
/etc/sentry/sentry.conf.py
/etc/sentry/config.yml
```

Answer (score 2):

The below command is deprecated now,

```
sentry config set system.url-prefix
```

The better option to edit vim ~/.sentry/config.yml.
Add the below line at the end of vim ~/.sentry/config.yml & restart the sentry.

```
system.url-prefix: 'https://sentry.example.com'
```